# What is the best way to apply 0.1 kV- 5kV difference between two plates?

Tags: power-supply, high-voltage

I want an electric field to act on ions in solution so I don't expect much work to be done. I need the voltage to be maintained over a 24h period and be adjustable between 0.1kV and 5kV.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Get a 5 kV lab power supply and don't worry about designing it yourself. High voltage stuff is not something you want to mess with yourself. Leave it to Stanford Research or Magna-Power or whoever.

Comment: What is your budget?

Comment: for Ions in solution more usual volatages are in the 0.1 to 5V range.

Comment: 0.1 to 5V is per angstrom, I believe.

Comment: Since there is no current flow there should be no need for expensive or dangerous equipment. A spark gap generator in a welding machine easily generates higher voltages with no risk to the operator. I figured the answer would be to use a capacitor in some simple circuit.